# assigning nodes to a new parent using pugixml

Tags: c++, pugixml

I use pugixml to read a svg document.

After I read the svg I have a pugixml::document like this (simplified):

```
<svg>
    <rect .../>
    <text ...> text </text>
    <line .../>
</svg
```

After reading I want to wrap some of the child nodes into a g element, like so:

```
<svg>
    <g ...>
        <rect .../>
        <text ...> text </text>
    </g>
    <line .../>
</svg>
```

How can I do this, preferably by modifying the pugixml::document in place and not creating a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
pugi::xml_node g = svg.prepend_node("g");

g.append_copy(svg.child("rect"));
svg.remove_child("rect");

g.append_copy(svg.child("text"));
svg.remove_child("text");
```